# How to use Chrome debugging on a signed Cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, debugging, chrome-remote-debugging

I have been using the Chrome remote device inspector to debug my Cordova app. The debug version of my app has been working fine without errors. However, now I made a signed APK for the first time, which installs and opens up, but hangs in a loading screen when try to use the login functionality in my app.

I believe this could be caused by some error in a plugin, or perhaps Google Maps Javascript API failing to load, but I cannot find out what it is because the Chrome debugging is disabled in a signed app. Is there any way I can turn on the debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you can turn on debugging by adding android:debuggable="true" in AndroidManifest in manifest and application tags.

Comment: For anyone looking for similar solution for cordova, it is to be added as `<application android:debuggable="true" />` between `<edit-config ...attributes>put_here</edit-config>` tags or between `<config-file ...attributes>put_here</config-file>` tags in your config.xml file. Or just do it directly in AndroidManifest file